# My USB microscope stoped working

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I have USB microscope and this is the hardware number:
USB\VID_05E3&PID_0510&REV_0509&MI_00

And the PC recognize it as Lenovo easy camera.
And it's true.

My OS: windows 10

What I have tried:

- Uninstall all drivers and install them again.
- Uninstall USB hubs and install them again.
- Connect the Microscope to other PC **and it works!**
- Update windows 10 and drivers.
- Connect it to different USB port.
- Remove all USB devices and just connect the microscope.
- I have tried different apps with it, the same thing "**black screen**"
- also I have restarted the PC several times.
- Also removed the USB cable and solder new one to be sure not from the wire.
- There is no errors at all in device maneger.

I usually use the built in camera app that came with windows 10 to show the microscope.

I was using the microscope, then sadenly black screen, all apps detect the microscope, but it's just black screen, no image, I thought the microscope have a problem, but It's works on other PC.

I just found this in the event of the device

```
Device USB\VID_05E3&PID_0510&MI_00\6&15937348&0&0000 was not migrated due to partial or ambiguous match.

Last Device Instance Id: USB\VID_0603&PID_8612&MI_00\7&8A774E8&0&0000
Class Guid: {6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F}
Location Path: 
Migration Rank: 0xF000FFFF0000F122
Present: false
Status: 0xC0000719
```

**Can anybody help me to make it works again!?**

Comment: So your PC recognises it? In what way is it not working?

Comment: Yes, recognizes the microscope, but just black screen, nothing there, like the camera not connected, I tired different apps the same, it works on my other pc, but not on this one, both computers have the same windows 10 version

Comment: Thanks for listening all the steps you've already tried... But can you edit your post and describe what it currently does or doesn't do? Just "My device stopped working" is very non-descriptive. Do you get an error? Does it not being recognized? is it recognized as the wrong device? Does your program says the device is not found but device manager shows it listed normally?

Comment: Also, silly question, but have you rebooted? Especially between steps? Rebooting can fix many weird issues, especially if a driver or service is involved.

Comment: @LPChip I have edited the question, Thanks for your time :)

Comment: This sounds like a graphics driver issue to me.  Video is often offloaded to a graphics driver, and I've seen black screens when the codec is not supported or there are other graphics driver related issues [ but I use Linux, not Windows, so this is a comment only !]

Comment: @davidgo There is other app on my PC changed the frame rate of the camera, for that it doesn't work, now it's working fine, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem!

If anybody have this issues with a microscope or any kind of camera, it because OBS program set the frame-rate out of range the camera, the only way to make it work is to Uninstall OBS program, or any program that can change the frame-rate of the camera.

Answer (score 0):

for allowing windows 10 connecting your camera or microscope usb to ur software

1-please go to **start** (press windows key)

2-type **camera privacy setting**

3-get access of camera to the program (****ON** the access** of program)

hope you enjoy it

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation recently.

Connect device to "USB Camera" app in Android and adjust "Power Line Frequency" setting from Disabled to Auto (or 50/60 Hz) will restore image. Looks like Windows 10 changes this setting.